# Toast giving incorrect answer from Radio box references

Tags: android, radio-button, toast

I am pretty new to this and are not entirely sure why I am having this problem.  From my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RadioButton wavelength1;
RadioButton wavelength2;

double ray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wavelength1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lowave);
    wavelength2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hiwave);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            If (wavelength1.isChecked());{
                ray = 0.7125;
            }
            If (wavelength2.isChecked());{
                ray = 0.4436;
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(ray), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        private void If(boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}


}
```

When I click on either radio boxes, the same output is given in the toast (as 0.4436) when they should be different. I am really at a loss to know what is going on.  The app is aimed at API 10 and I am using Eclipse.  (I am sure I am missing something).

Comment: why you have added comma(;) after If method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `semicolor(;)` at the end of if statement

`If (wavelength1.isChecked());`  < -- remove this

And also

**use small (i)  `if`  it is method `If();`**

remove this method

```
private void If(boolean checked) {
        }
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick - I knew I was missing something!  Thank you Pragnani!